# Panda contains formula with replace

Tags: python, pandas

I cant get if statement to work on 2 columns

Progress so far:

```
col1= example.com/abc/abs
```

Goal: to get output of the whats after last `"/"`

This worked:

```
df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.rsplit('/', 1, expand=True)[1]
```

I need help with this part:

If col2 contains `"/"`, then I want to replace col1 with it, otherwise leave col1 as is.

I tried but did not work:

```
df1['col1'] = np.where(df1['col2'] =="/" , df1['col2'], df1['col1'])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! The question could be improved by providing a simple dataframe to illustrate your situation and allow people to answer more concretely.

Comment: Use `df['col1'].str.rsplit('/', 1).str[1]`.

Comment: Hi @HenryYik, thanks for response. was this to replace the original (df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.rsplit('/', 1, expand=True)[1]) ? so i dont have to do 2nd step? i tried this and it doesnt work. the onces without "/" do not shows on col1. only ones that need to be changed show.

Comment: Then get rid of `rsplit` and just use plain split: `df["col2"] = df['col1'].str.split('/').str[-1]`.

Comment: thank you @HenryYik, that worked!!!! i dont need 2nd step "if statement" at all with this

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:**

```
df['col1'] = numpy.where(df['col2'].notna(), df['col2'], df['col1'])
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick response. this doesnt seem to work since col2 doesnt have any "/". with "df['col2'] = df['col1'].str.rsplit('/', 1, expand=True)[1]" it outputs response if there is "/" or leaves it blank. so i am trying to put in col2 into col1 (if col2 has a string) or use col1 (if col2 is blank)

Comment: So, col1 = col2 if col2 is not NaN ? Answer updated.

Comment: Hi, yes, that is correct. it looks like the output has some yes, no and Nans. Henry solved it above on the first line. would you know if the if statement required in case i need both lines for other string filters?